# .htaccess rewriting url to page or directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

For my site I have a RewriteRule that points the URL http://www.mysite.com/work to a work.php file. I also have a directory called "work" that has files in it, like project1.php, project2.php, etc...

What rules would I have to write so that the URL http://www.mysite.com/work knows to go to the work.php file, but the URL http://www.mysite.com/work/project1 knows I mean to go inside the directory "work" and display the project1.php file?

**EDIT**: Should point out, this is what I'm currently working with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Any additional tips to improve this security-wise? (Stopping directory jumping, etc...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^work$ /work.php [QSA,L]
```

That will ensure that `http://www.mysite.com/work` (no trailing slash) will go to your `work.php` file.

If you also want `http://www.mysite.com/work/` (with trailing slash) to go `work.php`, add this line just above the last `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule ^work/$ /work [R=301,QSA,L]
```

That will redirect it to the URL with no trailing slash thus, displaying the `work.php` file.

**UPDATE:** Since you already have a `RewriteBase` directive, just put the `RewriteRule` line(s) right after your `RewriteBase` but before your `RewriteRule` as the rule you're using a catch-all and will match everything.

Comment: You answered before I included my current .htaccess file, doesn't seem to work if I just add your stuff in. Probably something to do with what I currently have?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question. It works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Simply remove `beta/`

Answer (score -1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted it, but I'd guess the reason is your rule is too aggressive and will match any file that exists and not just `/work`, which is what OP wanted.