# Give priority to file rather directory in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Consider I have a file 'fg' and a folder 'fg' in the same directory. Now when user visit, he/she get content of file rather than content of directory. How to do this using .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to .htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name) should be what you're after.

It is using the .htaccess file to rewrite directories to a file if both exist.