# htaccess - Rewrite files that have a directory with the same name

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that has multiple PHP files and directories with the same name, like so:

```
/projects.php
/projects
/projects/something.php
```

I have managed to make http://example.com/projects rewrite to http://example.com/projects.php with the following rules (using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name)):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable automatic directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works, however, when I explicitly input the directory slash to the URL, it accesses the folder.
Right now:

```
http://example.com/projects   -->  http://example.com/projects.php  [file]
http://example.com/projects/  -->  http://example.com/projects/     [folder]
```

I know why it's doing this (`projects/.php` isn't a file). My attempt at fixing it consisted of checking if it was a folder, and replacing the slash with nothing and accessing that instead.

New .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable automatic directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Folder fix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php
```

This works as intended, however it completely messes up on the client side, as the client still has a folder in it's URL, so when it tries to fetch relative paths, it fails miserably.

Now I thought about doing a redirect with the `[R=301]` flag but as far as I know, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is relative to the server, so redirecting to that wouldn't work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: it's crazy that my folder name is 'projects' as well xd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting this line at the top:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

[Read More About it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html)

**Your .php hiding rule should be:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable automatic directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This does not fix my issue, unfortunately. Thanks though, learned something new!

Comment: That does not work either. Now http://example.com/projects points to the folder instead.

Comment: so `example.com/projects` is not loading `example.com/projects.php` and opening folder `example.com/projects/` ?

Comment: Precisely, probably due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested this by creating a file called projects.php and a folder project and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work either, seems like it should. Check if your folder has the same name (`projects` not `project`)?

Comment: I have exactly same name `/projects` and `/projects.php`

Comment: Oh wait, I'm working in a subfolder, could that be the issue?

Comment: Fixed my issue, I simply added my subfolder in the rewrite rules. Thanks!

Comment: @anumhava I spoke too fast... my initial issue with the relative paths is still there. The client still thinks I'm in a folder :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40656/discussion-between-anubhava-and-lemon42)