# How can I maintain a website where a folder and file have the same name but also hide the extension of that file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to improve the structure of my urls by using .htaccess. I have a file named `foo.php` and a folder named `/foo`. I want to be able to access `example.com/foo` and show `example.com/foo.php`. I also want to be able to access `example.com/foo/bar` and show `example.com/foo/bar.php`. Lastly I want to reditrect from `example.com/foo/` to `example.com/foo`. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am able to remove the `.php` extension by I am not able to redirect from the folder to the file. I also tried the solutions below but none of them resulted in the desired behaviour.

[htaccess - Rewrite files that have a directory with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819236/htaccess-rewrite-files-that-have-a-directory-with-the-same-name)

[.htaccess, rewriting of filename with same name as directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361587/htaccess-rewriting-of-filename-with-same-name-as-directory)

[.htaccess, proper rewriting of directory and file with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name)

Comment: Which of the many things you want are you specifically asking about? The redirect? Or is it the order how configuration directives in Apache apply?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: @hakre I am trying to remove the extension of a file while also having a folder with the same name of the file redirect to it in the event that the folder is requested

Comment: Yes, that part I've understood, however from your question it is not that clear to me where you got stuck configuring the apache webserver. E.g. there is a redirect directive that comes to mind, but you don't mention it in your question so it remains undefined what by chance might be missing (the difference between what you want and what you got and why you think it did turn out this way - and equally fine - why you would insist it should have done otherwise). That is _your_ (current) understanding of the directives you made use of.

Comment: @hakre To be honest, I don't really understand much about the configuration. I found the code online and used it. I am hoping that I am able to add a redirect from the folder to the file. Currently, if I am to go to the folder, I get a 404 error. Instead, I want `example.com/foo/` to redirect `example.com/foo` rather than a not found error.

Comment: Sure, but well, if there are parts in it you don't understand, its much better you build it step by step so that you can reduce any problems. With just these requirements as you already have found out, there are tons of questions that unspecifically ask about that and then only provide very localized "code examples" that were once satisfying the person who asked but are of little use for future users that then get stuck again and again. Sometimes it may help if you at least provide reference where you got it from and what _your_ understanding is (hint: never "no clue", it's always learning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution to this problem. In order to remove the extension from file names, I used the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The above code allows me to go to `example.com/foo` and show `example.com/foo.php`. In order to redirect from `example.com/foo/` to `example.com/foo`, I created an `index.php` file in the `/foo` directory. I added the following PHP code to the file

```
<?php 
  $page = str_replace('/index.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  header("Location: $page");
?>
```

This redirects from the directory to the file. Hope this helps.