# how to rewrite directory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have folder name "user_panel" in my root folder and i want to rewrite that folder to "user" without user redirect.

Currently i am using following htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/?$ user_panel/$1/ [NC,L]
```

it's working if i am using

```
http://www.sitename.com/user/home/
```

it's not working if i am using

```
http://www.sitename.com/user/home
```

I had already written htaccess for "/home" and it's working fine if i am using

```
http://www.sitename.com/user_panel/home
```

or

```
http://www.sitename.com/user_panel/home/
```

I have one htaccess into "user_panel" folder and i had write rule like:

```
RewriteBase /user_panel/
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `I had already written htaccess for "/home"`

Comment: i have one htaccess into "user_panel" folder and i had write rule like: 

RewriteBase /user_panel/
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home/index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Is this the only `.htaccess` or you have another in root?

Comment: one in root and second in user_panel

Comment: Then place both .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/*?$ user_panel/$1/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry not working :(
It redirect me to original folder "usre_panel"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the slashes in the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^user\/(.*)\/?$ user_panel/$1/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: Rewrite rules don't need escaping forward slashes.

Comment: Sorry not working :(
It redirect me to original folder "usre_panel"

Comment: @Dipen: Of course it won't work. Looks like you have time to read answers and comment on them but don't want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user_panel/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

i think you also want QSA there, which comes from query string append. don't know if you have Multiviews enabled but i would definitely turn that off. a smart thing to do would be to have a script inside user_panel that manages your requests otherwise apache will scan if the request you have is a file/folder or valid resource inside that folder. a more common approach would be

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user_panel/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: There is one htaccess into user_panel folder for different parameters and i also tried QSA but it's not working :(

Comment: you will probably receive 20 more answers that don't work if you don't share the htaccess you have inside your user_panel folder :)

Comment: I had edit my question and added htaccess code of "user_panel" folder

Comment: you are rewriting your home folder without a slash to a file inside your home folder, your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name

Comment: I tried your link and it's show me page that i want but it changed url from "user" to "user_panel" (ie.: <siteName>/user_panel/home/).

Comment: your problem is with home, not user_panel. inside user_panel you have a folder "home" that exists, if you want to be able to access home without a trailing slash you need to set DirectorySlash Off