# .htaccess, rewriting of filename with same name as directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given a file structure as follows:

```
|- .htaccess (1) 
|- portfolio.html
|- portfolio(dir) -|
                   |- .htaccess (2)
```

I would like to rewrite any link with /portfolio to /portfolio.html. The problem is that there also exists a directory named portfolio.

This question is very similar to the one answered here:
[.htaccess, proper rewriting of directory and file with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name)
But unfortunately that doesn't quite solve my problem.

### Here are the proposed solutions for the accepted answer to the above link:

Solution 1: Manually re-route requests for the portfolio directory to remove the slash.

```
# Manually re-route portfolio/ requests to portfolio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} portfolio/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

The downside to this is that you are having to hard-code the "portfolio" edge case directly into the rewrite rules, and will still result in the browser being first redirected to portfolio/

Solution 2: Set DirectorySlash Off and remove directory exists test

```
# Disable Automatic Directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Setting DirectorySlash Off would fix this issue the best, but may break other parts of your site where you actually want the auto DirectorySlash.

---

And indeed the answer to the above linked stack overflow answer does solve the problem but only if there is no .htaccess rule in the directory with the same name as the filename, i.e. any rewriteRule in the .htacess (2) file shown above stops this working.

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work for you from your `htaccess (2)`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

# if .html exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%{ENV:BASE}.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution only works if there is no RewriteRule in the .htaccess in the directory (i.e. htaccess (2) in the above example). This is the same behaviour as the previous two solutions mentioned above.

Comment: No only if you have `RewriteEngine On` line in `htaccess (2)` then only it won't work. And that is expected behavior also since .htaccess is per directory directive so whatever is the closest parent's .htaccess that will be in effect. If you're open to edit `htaccess (2)` then this can be easily achieved.

Comment: What would I need to do to htaccess (2) to get this to work? Are you saying that I can't get this scenario working if I have the RewriteEngine On in htaccess (2)?

Comment: That seems to work thank you very much. I'll study the rules closely to see how you achieved it.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. This works by setting a dynamic `RewriteBase` variable in first rule.