# How to Have a File and Directory With Same Name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website that I am hosting on an Apache web server, and I have some files that have the same names (without extensions) as some directories.

I also have extensions removed in the .htaccess file:

```
#Remove .php from filenames
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For example, I have a file called test.php and a directory called test. When I go to http://redxtech.ca/test, it adds a slash to the URL and go to the contents of the directory test/.

I know that by just typing in the .php at the end of the file name it would fix my problem, but I wish to not have the .php (or any extension at all) be there, just the file name without extension to go to the file, and with a slash to go to the directory.

Is there any way that I would be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of scouting this site, I have found an answer.

```
# Manually re-route test/ requests to test
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} test/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 

# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The only thing is I have to do that separately for each directory that I wish to have this condition.

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name?rq=1).