# Index.php for Website Subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an `index.php` file for my website. All is well with that.

I've just created a new folder, where I'd like to have some different pages. This directory structure is as follows:

```
root
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
```

I'd like it to look something like:

```
root
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
    - <folder>
        - <index.php for folder>
        - customer.php
```

Is this possible? To have a separate index.php file for a subfolder? I believe it is, and so...

Ideally, the url (with `.htaccess` removing `.php` etc would then become:

`www.mywebsite.com/folder`

and the customer file would be accessed by

`www.mywebsite.com/folder/customer`

**Is this possible to do? Or do I specifically need to write
`www.mywebsite.com/folder/index`?**

If needed I can add a `.htaccess` to my `<folder>`.

---

Another possible solution:

Have both a `<folder>.php` file as well as a directory named `<folder>`, and then the index page goes to the php file while any files deeper down route to files inside the `<folder>` directory. The only issue with this is modifying the .`htaccess` to know to go to the php file rather than the directory when you go to `www.mywebsite.com/<folder>`

---

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteEngine On
```

Thanks

Comment: Every single folder can have an `index.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this doesn't address the second part of my question, would you be able to answer it?

Comment: I think you are looking for URL rewrites. So that you don't have to add index.php against every folder (path)

Comment: Hi @vishwakarma09, I added my `.htaccess` as well as I believe I am partially trying this, thank you

Comment: what is the content of your .htaccess in root folder? I believe this htaccess in chid folder routes all non existent files of this folder to index.php

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with just manually forcing the page to show the file vs the directory, thanks to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017766/3784049).

```
# Manually re-route <folder>/ requests to folder.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} <folder>/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
```