# How to create a map on your webserver that has the same name as a permalink without having a 403 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

In Wordpress we created some pages like

- website.com/page-1/

  - website.com/page-1/subpage-1/
  - website.com/page-1/subpage-2/
- website.com/page-2/

  - etc. etc.

Now on the FTP we also created a map called 'page-1'. This map only contains another folder called 'app' (so we have website.com/page-1/app).

Now some visits are getting a 403 error on 'website.com/page-1' because the server does not route the traffic to Wordpress but to the -almost empty- folder on the FTP called 'page-1'. Most browsers do fine, SEO checkers and some proxy's do not route to the Wordpress page.

Can I resolve this issue so that visitors are always getting to the Wordpress page when visiting 'website.com/page-1'?

When I delete the folder called 'page-1' the issue is resolved. Too bad I need this folder because an emailing went out with this specific URL.

Comment: do yyou want to redirect users from **website.com/page-1** to **website.com/page-1/app**?

Comment: No. We have a Wordpress page called website.com/page-1/
And now we created a folder sturcture in the root of our website: /page-1/app/

Now when users visit website.com/page-1/ users mostly route to the Wordpress page but some end up getting a 403 error because there is an existing map with the same name (page-1).

So if we talk about redirection: website.com/page-1/ should redirect to Wordpress and not 'open' the folder called page-1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748/htaccess-proper-rewriting-of-directory-and-file-with-same-name and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name