# How can I create a redirect with .htaccess to correct path instead of page acess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am making a multilingual dynamic site that creates a virtual path per language.

So french pages go to domain.com/fr/ english domain.com/en/page domain.com/fr/some/page but in reality these pages are in the base folder and /fr/ is converted to a query string.

This is all working with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash Off # Fixes the issue where a page and folder can have the same name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# Remove virtual language/locale component
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/$  index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

My problem is that some sites (Like a Linkedin post) somehow remove the trailing / in the index page automatically. So if I put a link in my post of domain.com/fr/ somehow they make the link domain.com/fr even if it shows domain.com/fr/ but that 404's as domain.com/fr dosent exist.

So how can I redirect domain.com/fr to domain.com/fr/ or localhost/mypath/fr (There's many sites in my local workstation) to localhost/mypath/fr/.

I tried something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(en|fr)$ $1/$2/ [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ $1/ [L,QSA,R=301]
```

But that ended up somehow adding the full real computer path in the url:
localhost/mypath/fr becomes localhost/thepathofthewebserverinmypc/mypath/fr/

I would very much appreciate some help as I have yet to find the right rule.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ $1/ [L,QSA,R=301]
> ```

You are just missing the slash prefix on the *substitution* string. Consequently, Apache applies the directory-prefix to the *relative* URL, which results in the malformed redirect.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The *substitution* is now a root-relative URL path and Apache just prefixes the scheme + hostname to the external redirect. (The `QSA` flag is unnecessary here, since any query string is appended by default.)

This needs to go *before* the existing rewrites (and after the blocking rule for `.php` requests).

Note that the "internal rewrite" directives are correct to not have the slash prefix.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> DirectorySlash Off
> ```

Note that if you disable the directory slash, you must ensure that auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex) are also disabled, otherwise if a directory without a trailing slash is requested then a directory listing will be generated (exposing your file structure), even though there might be a DirectoryIndex document in that directory.

For example, include the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> this worked on the production server. As the site is in the server root. Would your know how can I also try and "catch" this on my localhost ? `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(en|fr)$ /$1/$2/ [L,R=301]`  dosent catch but with only `RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` `localhost/mypath/fr` becomes `localhost/fr/`

From that I assume the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/mypath` subdirectory on your local development server.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches the URL-path *relative* to the location of the `.htaccess` file (so it does not match `/mypath`). You can then make use of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* that contains the entire (root-relative) URL-path.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable already includes the slash prefix.

This rule would work OK on both development (in a subdirectory) and in production (root directory), so it should replace the rule above if you need to support both environments with a single `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Amazing thank you, this worked on the production server. As the site is in the server root. Would your know how can I also try and "catch" this on my localhost ? ```RewriteRule ^(.*)/(en|fr)$ /$1/$2/ [L,R=301] ``` dosent catch but with only ```RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]``` localhost/mypath/fr becomes localhost/fr/

Comment: @FabriceQuenneville If the site (and `.htaccess` file) is in a subdirectory then you will need to modify the rule to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Amazing thank you, this did it both in localhost and production.