# How to handle multiple errors in apache? / What's wrong with my htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I am rewriting an old website for a friend and I used my usual htaccess file for php sites with some added redirects for the moved or removed urls. But when I tested the redirects or removed URLs to test the error handlers apache gave me some errors saying a 404 was happening during the 410.

I have isolated the issues to my php extension remover and the 301/410 conflicting but everything i've tried I still get undesired errors or behaviors.

So here is what I was going to do:

```
# Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
# Images
AddType image/x-icon                    ico
AddType image/webp                      webp
ExpiresByType image/*                           "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg                         "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg                        "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon                      "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/webp                        "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif                         "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png                         "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                     "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css                          "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf                   "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript                 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash     "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon                      "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon          "access plus 1 year"

# Fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                   otf
AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
AddType application/x-font-woff2        woff2

ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject     "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf            "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/opentype                     "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff           "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2          "access plus 1 year"

# Rewrites
RewriteEngine on
# Erreurs
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 410 /error.php

# Autre rewrites
DirectorySlash Off # Fixes the issue where a page and folder can have the same name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017748
# Disable auto-generated directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect some/path/fr to some/path/fr/
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Permanent redirects for old URLs to new URLs
Redirect 301 /oldpath/oldpage.php /fr/newpath/newpage
Redirect 301 /oldpath/oldpageen.php /en/newpath/newpage

# Handle removal of old pages with a 410 status
RewriteRule ^oldpath/banana\.php$ - [G,L]
RewriteRule ^oldpath/apple\.php$ - [G,L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# Remove virtual language/locale component
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/$  index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]


# RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*?)/?$ $2/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
# ExpiresByType                                 "access plus 1 month"
```

---

But when going to http://somedom.xyz/oldpath/banana.php

It triggers:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpath/banana\.php$ - [G,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Giving this error:

```
Gone
The requested resource is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) Server at
```

But removing one of the two rules triggers the correct, now isolated, error and error handling page.

---

And when going to http://somedom.xyz/oldpath/oldpage.php

It triggers:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpath/oldpage.php /fr/newpath/newpage
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Giving this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

But when going to http://somedom.xyz/oldpath/oldpage it redirects to http://somedom.xyz/fr/newpath/newpage.

---

I tried a few things including excluding the specific URLs:

```
# Return a 404 status for URLs with .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
# Exclude specific URLs from this rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oldpath/oldpage\.php$
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

And I also tried that it would not trigger on existing errors but that didn't work:

```
# Set an environment variable if an error status is set
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_ERROR:1]

# Handle 404 for URLs with .php extension if NO_ERROR is not set
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteCond %{ENV:NO_ERROR} !1
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Both still give:

```
Gone
The requested resource is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I am not sure what to do at this point but ignore the old URLs but then I still have the issue that visitors of the old URL's end up with a dual 404 (Missing page + php file extension) resulting in an apache error page instead of my error handling page.

Anyone with a recommendation ?

Is there a way to overwrite any errors even multiple errors to send the visitor to the error handler ?

Thank you

Comment: If you have access to the server/vhost configuration, I'd add some rewrite logging, to see what exactly is going on.