# Rerouting file to folder/directory name, but preserving directory children in Apache

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder and a file with the same name, for example `main.html` and `main/`. I have the following rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

These rules are made to remove all the `.html` extensions from the `.html` files when they are served to the browser.

How can I tell the browser to recognise that I want to view `main.html` without `.html` extension, not the `main` folder?

If this is not possible to do I am fine with having this `main.html` file in `main` folder, but when calling the `main.html` it should display the `../main/` instead of `../main/main.html`. How would I do that?

If I specify the full path in the code like so: `<a href="main.html"></a>`, browser will display the `.html` ending. But if I change it to `<a href="main"></a>` browser says that there is nothing to load in the `main/` and returns `403 Forbidden` error.

**Update:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} main/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
```

Adding the rules above sort of works, but now I cannot access sub-directories in `main` directory because it gets redirected to `main` file.

Tried the following solutions without success:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2017766/5153030
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237547/5153030

Comment: You need to disable directory slash, add this line to your htaccess : **DirectorySlash off** .

Comment: Specifying `DirectorySlash off` will not allow me to access anything in `main/file1.html` as I understand. After applying `DirectorySlash off` issue persists.

Comment: then There is something else going on. DirectorySlash off works fine on my server. Try changing your rule's pattern to **^([^/.]+)$** .